# How do you sum values in a cross table in google docs

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I would like a formula that adds values in a table based on a condition on the row and column.

For example, if I had a condition of row # + column # >= 35, then the return value would be 0.000007673360 + 0.000015346720 + 0.000015346720

The best thing I can do right now is to create another table with boolean values and then use sum product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formulas `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` together with `ROW` and `COLUMN`.

For example:

> `=sumif(ROW(A1)+COLUMN(A1),">35",A2)`

Where "A1" is the range used to check the condition, and "A2" is the range to sum if condition is met.

---

**References:**

- [COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472)
- [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472)
- [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)
- [SUMIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en)